# how to get the data schema of a mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for a mongodb query to retrieve the data schema of an already existing collection:
Here is an example :

```
{
    "test0": 1,
    "test1" : "aaa",
    "test2" : true,
    
},
{
    "test1" : "aaa",
    "test2" : true,
    "test3" : true,
},
{
    "test1" : "aaa",
    "test2" : true,
    "test3" : true,
    "test4" : {
    key: "value"
    }
}
```

and I would like to have the following result :

```
{
    "test0": Number,
    "test1" : STRING,
    "test2" : BOOLEAN,
    "test3" : BOOLEAN,
    "test4" : OBJECT
}
```

I thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can find the schema structure from Compass GUI tool. Look for details for the Schema <TAB> of the GUI.

Comment: Thank you for this info !
But isn't there a specific request to do so?
Because I'm on Robot 3T